# Python CRUD: How to resolve 'TypeError: update_profile() missing 5 required positional arguments' when updating SQLite3 database?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, crud

I'm Using Python CRUD and trying to connecting to my SQLite 3 database, but I get the following error:

> ( TypeError: update_profile() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'name', 'age', 'gender', 'height', and 'weight' )

Here is my code:

```py
def update_profile(self, name, age, gender, height, weight):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("users_db.db")
        c = conn.cursor() 
        c.execute("""UPDATE table_name SET name=?, age=?, gender=?, height=?, weight=? WHERE name=?, age=?, gender=?, height=?, weight=?""",
          (new_name, new_age, new_gender, new_height, new_weight, old_name, old_age, old_gender, old_height, old_weight))
        
        new_name = name.entry.get()
        new_age = age.entry.get()
        new_gender = gender.entry.get()
        new_height = height.entry.get()
        new_weight = weight.entry.get()
 
        
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM name=?, age=?, gender=?, height=?, weight=?, WHERE name=?, age=?, gender=?, height=?, weight=?",(new_name, new_age, new_gender, new_height, new_weight, old_name, old_age, old_gender, old_height, old_weight))
        
        datas = c.fetchall()
        for datas in datas:
            print(datas)


        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: please format the question so that the code is readable.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is a TypeError indicating that the update_profile() function is missing five required positional arguments: 'name', 'age', 'gender', 'height', and 'weight'. It seems like you are trying to retrieve the values for these arguments from some input fields (entry.get()). However, the code provided has a few issues that need to be addressed.

Firstly, there are some indentation errors in your code. Make sure the code within the update_profile() function is properly indented.

Secondly, in the SQL queries, you should use placeholders (?) to pass the parameter values instead of directly inserting them into the query string. This helps prevent SQL injection attacks and ensures proper formatting of values.

Here's an updated version of your code with the necessary corrections:

```
import sqlite3

def update_profile(self, name, age, gender, height, weight):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users_db.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    new_name = name.entry.get()
    new_age = age.entry.get()
    new_gender = gender.entry.get()
    new_height = height.entry.get()
    new_weight = weight.entry.get()
    
    c.execute("""
        UPDATE table_name 
        SET name=?, age=?, gender=?, height=?, weight=? 
        WHERE name=? AND age=? AND gender=? AND height=? AND weight=?
    """, (new_name, new_age, new_gender, new_height, new_weight, old_name, old_age, old_gender, old_height, old_weight))

    c.execute("""
        SELECT * 
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE name=? AND age=? AND gender=? AND height=? AND weight=?
    """, (new_name, new_age, new_gender, new_height, new_weight))
    
    datas = c.fetchall()
    for data in datas:
        print(data)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

In the updated code, I've removed the unnecessary placeholders from the SELECT query, as you don't need to specify the parameter names in the query. Instead, you pass the parameter values in the correct order when executing the query.

Please note that you still need to define the values for old_name, old_age, old_gender, old_height, and old_weight before calling the update_profile() function.